# Ansible: set fact variable is getting overwritten while iterating over a loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to create a list out of a dictionary based on condition. But when I pass it through a loop, the last value of loop overwrites the fact instead of creating a list

*input.yml*

```yaml
execution:
 pre-deploy:
   
 post-deploy:
   shell-files:
      name: abc, def, gef
      type: deploy
      target_host:  server1
      check:  enabled
   xml-files:
      name: xyz, uvw
      type: deploy
      target_host:  server2
      check:  enabled
  shell-files:
      name: pqr
      type: migrate
      target_host:  server1
      check:  enabled
```

My Code:

```yaml
  Hosts: local
  vars_file:
     - input.yml
  vars:
    post_list:"{{ lookup( 'dict', operations.post-deploy, wantList=Ture ) }}"
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
       get_deploy_list: "{{ item.key }}: {{ item.value.name.split(',') | list }}"
       get_host_list: "{{ item.value.target_host }}"
    when: ( item.value.type == "deploy" and item.value.check == "enabled")
    loop:"{{ post_list | items2dict }}"
  
  - debug: msg="{{ get_deploy_list }}"
```

Expected Output:

```yaml
  debug:
    [ {
      shell-files: abc,
      shell-files: def,
      shell-files: ghi
       }
     {
      xml-files: xyz,
      xml-files: uvw
     }  ]
```

Actual output:

```yaml
    [{
      xml-files: xyz,
      xml-files: uvw
     }  ]
```

The last value of list overwrites the fact.

Comment: If you could take a moment to properly format the code samples in your question it would be easier to read.

Comment: Unrelated: isn't Ansible complaining about `wantList=Ture`?

Answer (score 2):

The situation is the same as in any programming language with loops: if you don't reference the existing list, then it is just repeatedly reassigning a variable and you will end up with the last state of the world as the loop exits

The traditional way I have seen that solved is via `| default` and `| combine`

```yaml
- set_fact:
    get_deploy_list: >-
      {{ (get_deploy_list|default([]))
      | combine({item.key: item.value.name.split(',') | list})
      }}
  loop: "{{ post_list | items2dict }}"
```

although in my playbooks, I consider that pattern a bug since jinja is perfectly capable of building up dictionaries using its looping syntax, without invoking `set_fact` repeatedly (which, by definition, will open connections to every host in the inventory multiple times)

*be aware that I didn't get your exact output format with that code snippet, because there was already too much wrong with your playbook; this answer was just "why did the assignment overwrite the fact all the time"*